Did vscode-server change its directory structure and why?
I am trying to fix the weird behavior of VSCode in an air-gapped scenario. We use a similar approach to the one described here to bring vscode-server into an air-gaped environment.
VSCode server used to reside in this structure:
.vscode-server
└── bin
    ├── default_version -> e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
    └── e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39

Now it looks like this was changed. Version 1.88.1 now creates a structure like this:
.vscode-server
├── cli
│   └── servers
├── code-e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
├── data
│   ├── CachedProfilesData
│   ├── logs
│   ├── Machine
│   ├── machineid
│   └── User
└── extensions
    └── extensions.json

Our automatic setup, which creates a bundle of the most important plugins to be deployed in an air-gaped setup, now explodes in our hands.

Do you know about the motivation for this change?
Do the changes maintain the possibility to run multiple different versions of VSCode clients in parallel?
I could not immediately find the PR where this was introduced. Any hint is appreciated.
Bonus question (off-topic vent): Why can't people think about their data or filesystem structure and then create a product?


How do you automatically download the plugins/extensions for offline install?

I use a variant of https://gist.github.com/b01/0a16b6645ab7921b0910603dfb85e4fb#file-download-vs-code-server-sh

Do you have a method for also downloading the extensions as well via script?

Not yet, but see the recent discussion in the Gist.
